# running nginx/wusgi/mysql/django in docker container

Tags: django, nginx, docker, uwsgi

I have a docker image for running a django app. If I mount the dir containing the django app when I create the container it works fine. But I want to make the image self-contained and not dependent on the local file system. So I changed the Dockerfile to copy the dir containing the django app from the host machine into the image. But then, when I create the container (without mounting the dir) I get permission denied on all accesses to that dir (e.g. the socket, the static files, ...). Everything is world readable and executable. Anyone have any clues as to what could be causing this?

Comment: share ur docker file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it. Turned out one of the dirs in the path was not readable. That is, the django app was in /foo/bar/baz and although /foo and /foo/bar/baz were readable, /foo/bar was not. Once I chmod-ed that all was well.